# vim ctags method of store your own information

Tags: vim, ctags

I want to use vim and ctags for storing my own information in one folder. Is any way to implement this ?

Example: i want to insert a piece of information about mysql, im creating a file or other new structure which can be parsed  by ctags in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can implement it in two ways as follows

- Create 2 files in a folder tags & toc
- Now add a piece of information (the bit about mysql) in a 3rd file called data , use a pattern such
  as TOPIC: MySql as the heading for this piece of info
- Now You can write a script to automatically build your toc & tags file, but for this
  excercise we will do it manually

data file contents

```
blah
--Lots of other data
blah
TOPIC: MySql nugget
MySql is a cool open-source database. 
But Cassandra & NoSql are all the rage today.
```

tags file contents

```
MySql   data    /^TOPIC: MySql$/;"
```

toc file contents

```
Table of Contents
    MySql
```

Now load up the toc file place your cursor on M of MySql and hit Ctrl ] it should automatically load up the data file and place your cursor at the begining of TOPIC: MySql

You can create any number of data files, each having any number of TOPIC: strings and you can create any number of patterns (in effect) [devise your own language](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html) and have ctags automatically create a tags for you.FORMAT